# Как запустить все UI тесты на всех устроствах последовательно?

Tags: android, test-automation

Возможно ли запустить все `UI` тесты на всех подключенных устройствах последовательно? (Все тесты прогнались на первом устройстве, далее запускаются на втором и т.д.)

Есть возможность запустить их параллельно используя команду:

```
./gradlew connectedCheck
```

но мне это не подходит

Comment: Наверное, только если свой таск напишете. Можно узнать, зачем вам это?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Хочу иметь возможность запускать тесты на всех девайсах одной коммандой, но параллельно не подходит из-за специфики тестов